# Extract date from filename using bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I know that similar things have been asked before, but I haven't been able to really make hand and foot out of what's been posted.

I've got a whole bunch of files that contain the date in the format YYYYMMDD at some point in the filename. Luckily this is the only 8 digit substring in all the filenames!

I will need to write the dates into another file later, but that should be fine. I'm struggling to extract the date into a variable first...

I know I can get it with grep:

```
for d in $( ls *.csv | grep -Po "\d{8}"; do 
echo $d done
```

However, as I want to get the full filename into a variable too while I iterate through them, that's not an option right now.

I've tried using sed, but I don't think I know how to use it:

```
for f in $( ls *.csv ); do
    d=$( $f | sed -e 's/^.*\(\d{8}\).*$')
    echo $d
done
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Could you post some example filenames?

Comment: There's no need for `sed` here at all; bash can do regular expression matching natively.

Comment: ...also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^-- important: bash, not not /bin/sh

for f in *.csv; do                       # Don't use ls for iterating over filenames
  [[ $f =~ [[:digit:]]{8} ]] && {        # native built-in regex matching
    number=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}            # ...refer to the matched content...
    echo "Found $number in filename $f"  # ...and emit output.
  }
done
```

Comment: I'm afraid both solutions give me the error: something.sh: 19: something.sh: [[: not found

Comment: @dengar81, that means your shell isn't bash; you tagged your question `bash`, not `sh`, so use bash as your shell: Start your script with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh` -- and, when running at a prompt, `bash yourscript`, not `sh yourscript`.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through your csv files like this (don't parse `ls`):

```
for f in *.csv; do
    echo "$f"
    d=$(echo "$f" | grep -oE '[0-9]{8}')
done
```

I've used grep in extended mode (`-E`) but perl mode is equally valid.

As you have tagged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you can do `d=$(grep -oE '[0-9]{8}' <<<"$f"` instead if you prefer. You can also use built-in regular expression support, which is slightly more verbose but saves calling an external tool:

```
re='[0-9]{8}'
[[ $f =~ $re ]] && d="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
```

The array `BASH_REMATCH` contains the matches to the regular expression. If there is a match, we assign it to `d`.

Comment: Assigning the regex to a variable before using `=~` -- as you do here -- is definitely the better practice for anyone who needs compatibility with older versions of bash. Do you remember which releases it is where this matters? My memory is telling me it's 3.0-era, but I'm not sure how much I trust it.

Comment: @Charles I'm not sure of the details to be honest, I just always do it like this because a wise man called Greg told me to - some discussion on the difference between versions is here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions